# new array be joining 2 arrays at random

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, random

Dear stackoverflow members,
I want to join 2 arrays in random as mentioned below, i tried different methods but i was not able to produce the result that i exactly wanted.

I have 2 arrays which looks like this. Lets call this **names**.

```
Array
(
    [bill] => Array
        (
        )

    [steve] => Array
        (
        )

    [Ritchie] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

now these names are generated from another function, it's output looks something like this.

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [email] => info@bill.com
            [name] => bill
            [web] => http://bill.com
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [email] => rich@steve.com
            [name] => steve
            [web] => http://steve.com
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [email] => god@linux.com
            [name] => Ritchie
            [web] => http://linux.com
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [email] => dummy@dummy.com
            [name] => Ritchie
            [web] => http://linux.com
        )

)
```

and the 2nd array, lets call it **countries**.

```
Array
(
    [0] => USA
    [1] => UK
    [2] => Netherlands
    [3] => Australia
    [4] => Germany
)
```

Now here is the exact problem. i want the 1st array **names** and the 2nd array **countries** to be joined and form another associative array in random order. But please note that the function which returns the **name** array returns the key : **Ritchie** twice, it has 2 occurrences. So the final array should be something like this.

```
Array
(

    [Ritchie] => Array
        (
            [0] => USA,
            [1] => Germany
        )

    [bill] => Array
        (
            [0] => Netherlands
        )

    [steve] => Array
        (
            [0] => UK
        )

)
```

Since the key **Ritchie** has 2 occurrences, 2 unique values from the **country** array should be added. The number of keys or occurrences in **names** and the keys in **countries** will always be the same. If their is anything unclear, let me know i'll clear it out.

---

I did heavy research on the internet and stackoverflow and i was only able to come up with this. The current solution i have is this. Please be kind to help me to improve the current lines of code to suit my need or may be this might not be elegant, if so, please be kind to suggest a better solution.

```
$jumble = array();
  foreach ($names as $name) {
  $jumble[$name] = $countries[array_rand($countries)];
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
shuffle($countries);
$n = count($countries); $i = 0;
$jumble = array();
foreach ($names as $name) {
    if (!isset($jumble[$name])) $jumble[$name] = array();
    $jumble[$name][] = $countries[$i++ % $n];
}
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/O9QSpi)

Comment: Sorry, I did syntax mistake (in if stattement) Fixed

Comment: yeah i managed to fix it. 
Actually my function had a problem. it works perfectly now.

Thank you.